# How can I define a.json property "child" depends on b.json property "parent" in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

b.json

```json
{
  "parent": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

a.json, `child` should be value of `parent`

```json
{"child": 1}
```

How do I define this in JSON schema ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a highly requested feature of JSON Schema, however nothing proposed so far has been adopted for various reasons (mostly disagreement on how it should work).  So it's not going to be supported for vanilla JSON Schema

Happily, I've created a [vocabulary](https://gregsdennis.github.io/json-everything/usage/vocabs-data.html) that does exactly this.  To my knowledge, my [extension library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net.Data/) is the only implementation so far, which means you'll need to do it in .Net.